# ddrescure raw image? lvm encryption lubuntu hard drive to usb drive

Tags: lvm, ddrescue

I've read I should ddrescue my not-booting hard drive in raw to a larger USB drive. I read this
[GNU ddrescue Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html) but I'm sure which command to use, and whether to chose direct disk access or raw? **I am a linux newbie.**

Currently in progress, estimated time left: 8 days:

`ddrescue -f /dev/sda /dev/sdb logfile 
e2fsck -v -f /dev/sdb
mount -t ext2 -o ro /dev/sdb /mnt`

**Update**: I bought a new USB hard drive and use it as target. ddrescue has been running for some hours at 400 kB/s. So it will take more than a week a current pace. The laptop is quite old so I worried the heat accumulation might hurt the drive?

Then I read this another recommendation that I should first do a fast -n before running the slower, thorough method. I wonder if this would still be a useful method, considering 5 GB has been rescued already?
[ddrescue --no-split (cached reads)](https://superuser.com/a/786544)

When I installed lubuntu 13.10 I encrypted it with LVM. Then I upgraded to 14.04 when it was released and now it won't boot.

Live CDs can mount the 255MB volume sda1 (boot) but not the sda2 and sd5 partitions.

`sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda`

which returned among other things:

`Device boot - Start - End -       Blocks    - Id - System
/dev/sda1 * - 2048   - 499711 -    248832    - 83 - Linux
/dev/sda2   - 501758 - 976769023 - 488133632 - 5  - Extended 
/dev/sda5   - 501760 - 976769023 - 488133632 - 8e - Linux LVM`

For more on the background, see here: [How to recover encrypted LUKS lubuntu data?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/537873/how-to-recover-encrypted-luks-lubuntu-data)

This ddrescue suggestion also gave me a hint: [USB rescue data - ddrescue answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/191338/339324)

Comment: if you use /dev/sdb as output you will overwrite the device including the partition table. I would save the data you want to keep on /dev/sdb1 elsewhere first, or choose a different existing target for the recovery. I've never had need for the ddrescue switches. just specifying input output and logfile have always worked fine in my experience.

Comment: Ok, I glad I asked before trying that. I don't have enough any free storage to save the sdb1 data anywhere else, so then naming the output folder (see my updated guess) would work?

Comment: for starters, looking at the first line: I see no reason to use -f, to overwrite output device or partition
 or -n, to avoid splitting or retrying failed blocks. The ability to split and retry failed blocks is the entire reason to use ddrescue IMHO. Honestly I don't see anything in your question that would indicate the need for any switches (well -r 3 is permissible if you truly want to limit retries to 3, but I wouldn't personally use that switch either) Keep in mind you will need enough available storage to save the entire device chosen as input on the output (/dev/sda or /dev/sda5)